# How can I add a success flash message for the password reset functionality of Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and the built-in auth functionality.  When testing it, however, I noticed there is no "Success" message when a user fills out the forgotten password form, the page simply refreshes, although the form does work.

How can I set a success variable for the forgotten password tool?  I can't find the method that controls this anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you’re using Laravel’s built-in password reset functionality, then it *does* have a success message. You can see it here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php#L95

You merely need to listen for it in your view and display it if it’s there:

```
@if (session('status'))
   <p class="alert alert-success">{{ session('status') }}</p>
@endif
```

This will display the default message, which is:

> Your password has been reset!

If you want to change this message, just change the relevant line in **resources/lang/en/passwords.php**.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  Not sure why this has been omitted from the docs, when they specify full code for each of the required views

Comment: I’m guessing because there isn’t a standard route the password resetter redirects to with it being user-configurable, so it’s up to the user which view they use.

Comment: There is a bracket missing after the first ('status') in the above code, in case anyone misses it like I did :) Should be:

    `@if(session('status'))`

Comment: @NickF Thanks for the heads up! Amended now.

Answer (score -2):

Simply paste this function in your ***ResetPasswordController***

```
protected function sendResetResponse(Request $request, $response)
{
    return redirect($this->redirectPath())
        ->with('success', 'Password changed successfully.');
}
```

And to get the message in your ***blade view***, use this code

```
 @if (session('status'))
     <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
         {{ session('status') }}
     </div>
 @endif
```

Comment: This is the same answer as the accepted one with 13 upvotes 6 years after it was posted...